# passing boolean value between class not working as intended

Tags: java, class, boolean

Im making a battleship game
I have 3 classes and a driver.

in the player class

i have this method

```
public  void hitownshiporGrenade(String[][] grid, String attack) {
    // checking if attack hits our ship, appropriate
    // if it does place an s in the  array

    if (attack.equals(s1)) {
        // -97 gives us a starting point at 0 for 'a' to
        // store in array, same for 49 and '1'
        grid[attack.charAt(0) - 97][attack.charAt(1) - 49] = "s "; 
        System.out.println("ship hit!");                                                            
        s1Sunk = true;
    }
```

I have the declared variable and a getter on top

```
private boolean s1Sunk; 
public boolean isS1Sunk() {
    return s1Sunk;
}
```

Now in my other class

```
Player player = new Player();
System.out.println(player.isS1Sunk());
```

if i call this in a method in the driver it stays false nomatter what even if the first methods condition makes it true;

Comment: When you create a new instance of `Player`, it does not share it's state with other instances of `Player`, they can all have their own values for `isS1Sunk`.  This is where "model" in MVC is so important. You need to share the "model" with all the classes that need to work with it.  This is also a concept covered by [Passing Information to a Method or a Constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html)

Comment: Think of It this way: Every time you say "new Player" you are creating a NEW player, so unless your version of battleship has many players you probably shouldn't call new more than once.  Instead save and share 2 player objects (Only call "new" twice)

Comment: oh damn, ive been making alot of new objects in classes to pass methods around... im a bit confused on how to pass parameters then without the class name.method ? sorry this is my first real oop class ;(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the methods you mentioned in your code sample all belong to the same `Player` class definition, then creating a new class instance (an object) of `Player` by doing

```
Player player = new Player();
```

you create a new, separate (from all others) instance of the `Player` class. Unless you run `hitownshiporGrenade` for that SPECIFIC object, its variables aren't going to change.

---

Consider the following:

```
Player player1 = new Player(); //player1.isSunk is false
Player player2 = new Player(); //player2.isS1Sunk is again false,
                               //and separate from player1.isS1Sunk
player1.hitownshiporGrenade(foo, bar) //This changes player1.isSunk to true
System.out.print(player1.getIsSunk());    //true, assuming lucky hits
System.out.print(player2.getIsSunk());    //false
```

I'd also recommend you read up on using proper [Camel case when naming your variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case)! It's going to make your code much easier to read, and save you a lot of headache when you're going through it.

Comment: @Sacha E if your problem is resolved, consider accepting my answer and marking your question as resolved, by clicking the tick ✓ button under the upvote/downvote buttons.